# Execute Java EE 6 timer now

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I have a Java EE 6 timer - which I schedule with a ScheduleExpression but I also want to have the possibility to run it "now" on e.g. button click. How can I achieve this?

Example of how I create the timer:

```
ScheduleExpression schedExp = new ScheduleExpression();
    schedExp.start(jobInfo.getStartDate());
    schedExp.end(jobInfo.getEndDate());
    schedExp.second(jobInfo.getSecond());
    schedExp.minute(jobInfo.getMinute());
    schedExp.hour(jobInfo.getHour());
    schedExp.dayOfMonth(jobInfo.getDayOfMonth());
    schedExp.month(jobInfo.getMonth());
    schedExp.year(jobInfo.getYear());
    schedExp.dayOfWeek(jobInfo.getDayOfWeek());

TimerConfig timerConf = new TimerConfig(jobInfo, false);
Timer newTimer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedExp, timerConf);
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
timerService.runNow(timer);
```

Unfortunately there is no runNow method.

Comment: Can't you create a new timer with current time, so it will time out immediately & can cancel the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible but I somehow doubt it's needed either if you do the rest properly.

Say you could implement your Timeout method like this:

```
@Timeout
public void doTimeout(Timer timer) {
    logic.doMyTimeout();
}
```

Then what you need to do when the respective button is clicked is just call `logic.doMyTimeout();` as well.

Is there any reason not to use this approach?

Comment: I think there can be a valid reason for this. In the app I develop we've implemented the exact same thing, but used Quartz. The usecase is that you want to dynamically discover what timers (triggers in Quartz) there are and run those -exactly- how they are configured to be run.

Comment: That's a valid case, but the EJB `Timers` don't seem to be able to handle this, so one has to build a workaround or use something else like `Quartz` as you've done.

Comment: Indeed, unfortunately EJB timers can't be queried. The information is there in the container, but you need hacks and reflective tricks to get to it, which is of course not recommended.